# PassKit: Switch to Passbook and select pass

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook, passkit

I am trying to implement a "View in Passbook" functionality in our iOS app. I have been able to use PassKit to instantiate a `PKPass` object for an existing pass based on its serial number, but is there any way to open up this existing pass in Passbook from our app?

It seems an obvious capability that is strangely omitted from the SDK.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the passbook app from your own app using the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"shoebox://"]];
```

I haven't found a way to open to a specific pass but maybe this is good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. I take it "shoebox" was the codename for Passbook? ;)

Comment: Haha, It must be. Also you can see why this wouldn't be in any Apple documentation...

Comment: what is shoebox here?Is it a json file or what?